# Classifying spaces of monoidal categories and deloopings

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, classifying-spaces

$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{|#1|}$The **classifying space** $\abs{\mathcal{C}}$ of a category $\mathcal{C}$ is the [geometric realisation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization) $\abs{\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}(\mathcal{C})}$ of its [nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve) $\mathrm{N}_\bullet(\mathcal{C})$.

- When $\mathcal{C}$ is monoidal, we can however first [deloop](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping) it into a bicategory $\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C}$, which also has a classifying space, this time defined as the geometric realisation of its [*Duskin* nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Duskin+nerve) $|\mathrm{N}^{\mathrm{D}}_\bullet(\mathbf{B}\mathcal{{C}})|$.

(The simplicial set $\mathbf{B}_{\bullet}\mathcal{C}\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathrm{N}^{\mathrm{D}}_{\bullet}(\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C})$ is called the **classifying simplicial set of the monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$**; see [Kerodon, Tag 00FJ](https://kerodon.net/tag/00FJ).)

- Similarly, if $\mathcal{C}$ is *braided* monoidal, then we can deloop it twice, obtaining a tricategory $\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C}$, which again has a classifying space $\abs{\mathrm{N}^{\mathrm{S}}_{\bullet}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C})}$, the geometric realisation of its [Street Nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+nerve+of+a+tricategory).
- (Finally, we could in principle do the same for $\mathcal{C}$ *symmetric* monoidal, delooping it into a tetracategory and then taking the geometric realisation $\abs{\mathrm{N}^{?}_{\bullet}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C})}$ of its nerve, but the latter hasn't been constructed yet.)

**Question.** What is the relation between the homotopy types of the three spaces $\abs{\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}(\mathcal{C})}$, $|\mathrm{N}^{\mathrm{D}}_\bullet(\mathbf{B}\mathcal{{C}})|$, and $\abs{\mathrm{N}^{\mathrm{S}}_{\bullet}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}\mathcal{C})}$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific nerve constructions you mention, but are you asking if the "obvious guess is correct"? namely if $\mathcal C$ is an $\infty$-groupoid, i.e. "space" or "anima", equipped with $E_n$ structures for various $n$, i.e., n-fold loop spaces, then these spaces you're describing ("classifying spaces of deloopings") are literally (ignoring connectivity issues) just deloopings of each other, right? so one should hope the same is true in your setting. Or is your question all about the connectivity/grouplikeness assumptions I'm blithely ignoring?

Comment: @DavidBen-Zvi Yes, this is precisely what I'm hoping for to hold!